# In plpgsql, how can I create and execute a command-string using on a variable number of identifiers?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, plpgsql, variadic

In postgres 9.1 I'd like to create a function that takes an index name, a table name and a variable number of columns, constructs an index, and then does some other things.

My current approach is to use plpgsql and construct a dynamic command to execute.  However, I'm getting tripped up when trying to use `quote_ident` to protect all of the identifiers.  Code thus far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_create_index(indexname text, tablename text, VARIADIC arr text[]) RETURNS void AS $$
  DECLARE
    command_string text;
  BEGIN
    command_string := 'CREATE INDEX ' || quote_ident(indexname) || ' ON ' ||
         quote_ident(tablename) || ' (' ||
         format(repeat('%I ', array_length($3, 1)), VARIADIC $3) ||
         ')';

    -- display the string
    RAISE NOTICE '%', command_string;

    -- execute the string
    EXECUTE command_string;

    -- (do other stuff)
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The code appears to be successful when passing one column name, but with two or more I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  too few arguments for format
```

What am I doing wrong?  (Presumably something with `format` or my use of `VARIADIC`.)

Thank you!

Comment: I think you might've found a bug. See answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't generally to use both `format` and `quote_ident`. `format` is smart enough to do identifer quoting its self; you show that yourself in part of your expression, while using unnecessary concatenation and `quote_ident` calls elsewhere.

However, I'm seeing the same issue you are with calling `format` with a `VARIADIC` array argument, and I suspect you've found a bug.

Here's a workaround until I spot what's going on:

```
command_string := format('CREATE INDEX %I ON %I (%s)', 
    indexname, tablename, (
      SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(x), ', ') 
      FROM unnest($3) x
    )
);
```

Note that in your original code, `'%I '` should've been `'%I, '`.

Yes, bug confirmed, and [it's been reported before](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2012-09/msg00011.php) but looks like it never got checked up on. The same bug exists in `concat` and `concat_ws`. These functions fail to check for the `VARIADIC` argument flag.

Observe:

```
regress=> SELECT format('%I', VARIADIC ARRAY['b','c','d']);
  format   
-----------
 "{b,c,d}"
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT format('%I', 'b','c','d');
 format 
--------
 b
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT format('%I, %I, %I', VARIADIC ARRAY['b','c','d']);
ERROR:  too few arguments for format
```

The only workaround I can think of is either avoiding them (as shown above) or using `EXECUTE` to construct the function call dynamically. In the case of `format` that's totally redundant, so I'd just use the above sub-query with `unnest`.

I'll try to chase this up on the PostgreSQL mailing lists, but I'm going to be insanely busy next week, so poke me or post on pgsql-bugs with a link back to this question yourself if you don't see a follow-up by mid week-after-next.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough reply, I really appreciate it!  And yes, excellent point on my unnecessary use of both format and concatenation together.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a VARIADIC parameter in format function now :(. It is a known bug, that will be fixed in PostgreSQL 9.3 (I hope). You can try use patch http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRDZc7wG1ewnmqUWkjDsB78Pu=Oj_WZ8_CS7qJUCKRUNmQ@mail.gmail.com

Comment: Updated patch posted here: http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRDyXfXZcL2FRESLU-dPqaOKOu-ekKY12tBzdO559PW5uQ@mail.gmail.com

Comment: Further patch updates and tracking history can be found here: https://commitfest.postgresql.org/action/patch_view?id=970

Comment: Heroic effort getting that fix in. It looked relatively simple at first, but oh man...